# Showing that a function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain, $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
> continuos and for all closed triangles $\Delta \subset X$ applies
> $\int_{\partial\Delta}f \; dz = 0$. Show that $f$ is holomorphic.

I remembered the Cauchy-Goursat theorem (we used a special one with triangle contours as well):

[image]

Doesn't this theorem directly imply that $f$ is holomorphic?

Comment: No, Goursat is the other direction, "holomorphic implies vanishing integrals". The direction here, "vanishing integrals imply holomorphic" is Morera's theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer great, thank you!

Comment: @DanielFischer could you please create an answer from your comment, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (Morera's theorem) is the converse of Goursat's lemma (the special case for boundaries of triangles of the Cauchy-Goursat theorem). If

$$\int_{\partial\Delta} f(z)\,dz = 0\tag{1}$$

for all closed triangles $\Delta \subset X$, then we have local primitives of $f$ - if $D_r(z_0)$ is a disk contained in $X$, then

$$F(z) = \int_{[z_0,z]} f(\zeta)\,d\zeta$$

is holomorphic on $D_r(z_0)$ with derivative $f$: Given $z,w\in D_r(z_0)$, the closed triangle with vertices $z_0,z,w$ is contained in $D_r(z_0)$, hence in $X$, and $(1)$ yields

$$\begin{align}
F(w) - F(z) &= \int_{[z_0,w]}f(\zeta)\,d\zeta - \int_{[z_0,z]} f(\zeta)\,d\zeta\\
&= \int_{[z,w]} f(\zeta)\,d\zeta\\
&= \int_0^1 f(z+t(w-z))\cdot (w-z)\,dt\\
&= (w-z)f(z) + (w-z) \int_0^1 f(z+t(w-z))-f(z)\,dt,
\end{align}$$

and by the continuity of $f$,

$$\frac{F(w)-F(z)}{w-z} - f(z) = \int_0^1 f(z+t(w-z))-f(z)\,dt$$

converges to $0$ for $w\to z$. Thus $f$ is locally the derivative of a holomorphic function, hence itself holomorphic (as follows for example from Cauchy's integral formula).